# Why doesn't 'write' overwrites an open file everytime a loop iterates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the following code in Python:

```
L = ['vanilla', 6, 'chocola', 7]
txt = 'empty.txt'
f = open(txt,'w')
for item in L:
    f.write(str(item))
f.close()
f = open('empty.txt','r')
print(f.readlines())
f.close()
```

I ran it in Python and 'vanilla6chocola7' was printed
But shouldn't it print just '7'?

Doesn't 'write' overwrites everything in the file?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Opening the file in write mode starts at the beginning of the file, and every `write` advances the write position.

Answer (score 0):

To erase the content of a file before writing something else to it, use `.truncate(0)` before `.write(...)`.